# MySQL: Error #1067 when trying to add a boolean column with default 0

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm developing a feature to show to the users how many unread messages there is on the site. So I'm trying to execute this query:

```
alter table messages add read boolean not null default 0
```

But the server returns this message:

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'Data'

I can't see what is wrong. I'm running MariaDB/MySQL 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

Comment: Your column name is `read` but the server complains about `Data`, seems strange.

Comment: I found the problem. There's a column called "Data" that is set with a invalid default value

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The "Data" column is with a invalid default value. I got this database restored from a server that has a different MySQL version.

[image]